# Zeit builds failing - Error: No output directory named "build" found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vercel

As of 1/5/20 all of my builds are failing that are deployed on Now. I was getting the warning that node 8.x was no longer supported so I specified an engine version of 12.x in my package.json, this successfully stopped the warning from popping during deployment but I'm still receiving the following error

```
Error: No output directory named "build" found.
```

I thought maybe a recent change I pushed was causing this but going back and redeploying old deployments that built successfully now received this error. I'm wondering if something on the Now platform changed that I wasn't aware of because it does not seem that code I've pushed recently was the catalyst for this error.
It's also very odd since right before this error the deployment log shows the following

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.
File sizes after gzip:
207.04 KB build/static/js/2.7d84160a.chunk.js
11.64 KB build/static/js/main.65999b58.chunk.js
1.24 KB build/static/css/main.cacda93c.chunk.css
762 B build/static/js/runtime~main.a8a9905a.js
The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
"homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
```

So it looks like the build folder is created but now for some reason now can't find it.
My now.json looks like this

```
{
"version": 2,
"name": "appname",
"public": false,
"builds": [
  { "src": "package.json", "use": "@now/static-build" },
  { "src": "index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }
]
}
```

Any idea why my deployments would suddenly start failing in the last day?

Comment: Did you try to run these commands : `yarn run build && now ./build` where the build folder was generated

Answer (score 3):

Classic case of finding the solution as soon as I post on stackoverflow...

Not sure which tutorial I followed when first spinning this up but in my package.json I had my now-build script set to

```
react-scripts build && mv build dist
```

I removed the last bit of that so now my now-build script is simply

```
react-scripts build
```

and all is well again.

I couldn't really tell you why I set this, I just blindly followed the tutorial. For the past 4 months, this has worked, not sure why yesterday it started throwing errors, oh well.

Comment: I think there was a change in ZEIT's config. The same happened to me and was resolved as suggested. Great catch!